# chrome contextMenus onClick — получение информации о выбранном пункте

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, chrome-extension

Допустим, имеется список пунктов, при нажатии на которые срабатывает функция.

```
function func_1 {alert(1)};
function func_2 {alert(2)};
function func_3 {alert(3)};
...

chrome.contextMenus.create({"title": "item 1", "onclick": func_1});
chrome.contextMenus.create({"title": "item 2", "onclick": func_2});
chrome.contextMenus.create({"title": "item 3", "onclick": func_3});
...
```

А что, если таких пунктов 20 ??? Неужели для каждого создавать отдельную функцию ???

***Хотелось бы узнать, возможно ли как-то представить все пункты в виде массива ??? И можно ли программно получить title пункта, на который нажали ???***

Основная цель: объединить все функции в одну.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В callback функцию передаются два параметра info и tab  - onclick: function(info, tab). В первом содержится информация о пункте меню (например title содержится в info.menuItemId), во втором - информация о вкладке. Соответственно можно на callback повесить одну функцию агрегатор. Например функция выводящая при при клике информацию о пункте меню и вкладке:

```
function genericOnClick(info, tab) {
  console.log("item " + info.menuItemId + " was clicked");
  console.log("info: " + JSON.stringify(info));
  console.log("tab: " + JSON.stringify(tab));
}
chrome.contextMenus.create({"title": "item 1", "onclick": genericOnClick});
```

Comment: ► Спасибо, но пример в документации смотрел (https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/examples/api/contextMenus/basic/sample.js). Однако не понял, как формируется `menuItemId`, и почему при обновлении расширения (CTRL + R) `menuItemId` меняется. А если точнее, то увеличивается постоянно на одинаковое число.

► Про title тоже не понял. `info.title` возвращает undefined

Comment: А что JSON.stringify(info) возвращает? А id разный с каждым разом разный возвращает - потому-что ты его явно не назначил.

Comment: ► `JSON.stringify(info)` возвращает полную информацию. ► Теперь понял. Изначально думал, что `id` автоматически привязывается, но не понимал, из-за чего он меняется. Спасибо за ответ. ► А `title`, значит, никак нельзя получить.

Comment: Я сорри тоже заблуждение Вас ввел, конечно menuItemId к tile никакого отношения не имеет. Вот правда почему info.title возвращает undefined непонятно... Должно-же строчку в меню выводить.